# Storing data from stock data feed provider like Yahoo! Finance or FMP Cloud

Tags: finance, data-storage, disclaimers, data, database

Suppose a developer creates a web application for stock market alerts and notifications. Is it legal to store data obtained from purchased subscription of data feed providers like Yahoo! Finance or FMP cloud?

Also what is the effect and meaning of the term:

> You must not redistribute information displayed on or provided by provider.

It seems that this is included in the terms and conditions of every data provider.

Comment: One can downvote the question, but it would be great to hear advice or any kind of suggestions in comments so that I can understand my mistakes regarding my post

Comment: The downvote was likely for the same reason as the close vote: [the site does not accept questions which ask for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/3066). You should phrase your questions more generally in terms of the legal issue rather than the surrounding facts of your case.

Comment: As edited, I do not think this is a request for specific legal advice (RSLA). Indeed I don't think it really was before the edit, but now it should be clear. It should not be closed as a RSLA. It would be better had close voters done a similar edit, but no one is required to edit a question.

Comment: Licensing that data to publish it is extremely expensive, even on a 20 minute delay. Financial firms that provide that data to their customers pay millions a month for it, and their license has a lot of specific restrictions on who they can provide it to and what their customers are permitted to do with it. That’s why you see similar wording from different companies. For example, there is a distinction between “professional” users and “non-professional” users. Archival data is much cheaper than real time or near real time data and sometimes the exchanges will provide certain types for free.

Answer (score 1):

> You must not redistribute information displayed on or provided by provider

You (the subscriber) must not (is not allowed to) redistribute (give to anyone else) information (data) displayed (shown) on or provided by (supplied other than by display) provider (the subscription service).

Yes, you can store the data. No, you can’t share it with anyone else.